# Release for different target with Erts include

Tags: sql-server, odbc, elixir

I was wondering if somebody could help...

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL Server from within my Elixir app but I receive the error `:odbc.start/0 is undefined (module :odbc is not available)`.

On my Mac I installed Erlang with ODBC support and everything works fine, but when I do deployment with distillery and edeliver on a Ubuntu server (for which I installed erlang-odbc and where the build happens) it fails. I also tried not including erts and to build it locally after copying Erlang's lib on my machine, all to no avail.

This is a snippet from edeliver config file:

```
BUILD_HOST="search-dev"
BUILD_USER="ubuntu"
BUILD_AT="/home/ubuntu/app_build"

STAGING_HOSTS="search-dev search-demo"
STAGING_USER="ubuntu"
TEST_AT="/home/ubuntu/app_release"
...
```

#### UPDATE

mix.exs

```
defmodule SearchService.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :search_service,
      version: "0.9.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.7",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers(),
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  def application do
    [
      mod: {SearchService.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [
        :logger,
        :timex,
        :geo,
        :geo_postgis,
        :postgrex,
        :ecto,
        :runtime_tools,
        :distillery,
        :edeliver,
        :ssl,
        :httpoison
      ]
    ]
  end

  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]

  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.4.0", override: true},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"},
      {:plug, "~> 1.7"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.1"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.10"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
      {:elixir_uuid, "~> 1.2"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:cowboy, "~> 2.5"},
      {:scrivener_ecto, "~> 2.0"},
      {:erlport, "~> 0.10.0"},
      {:export, "~> 0.1.0"},
      {:cors_plug, "~> 1.2"},
      {:plug_static_index_html, "~> 1.0"},
      {:geo_postgis, "~> 2.0"},
      {:geo, "~> 3.0"},
      {:blue_bird, "~> 0.4"},
      {:edeliver, "~> 1.7"},
      {:distillery, "~> 2.1"},
      {:inflex, "~> 1.8.1"},
      {:guardian, "~> 1.0"},
      {:comeonin, "~> 4.0"},
      {:argon2_elixir, "~> 1.2"},
      {:elixlsx, "~> 0.4.0"},
      {:quantum, "~> 2.3"},
      {:timex, "~> 3.1"},
      {:httpoison, "~> 1.0"},
      {:sweet_xml, "~> 0.6.5"},
      {:math, "~> 0.3.0"},
      {:color_utils, "0.2.0"},
      {:paper_trail, "~> 0.8.1"},
      {:ex_aws, "~> 2.1"},
      {:ex_aws_s3, "~> 2.0"},
      {:ex_aws_lambda, "~> 2.0"},
      {:hackney, "~> 1.9"},
      {:policy_wonk, "~> 1.0.0"}
    ]
  end

  defp aliases do
    [
      "ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
      "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
      test: ["ecto.create --quiet -r SearchService.Repo", "ecto.migrate -r SearchService.Repo", "test"]
    ]
  end

  def blue_bird_info do
    [
      host: "https://search_service.com",
      title: " Search API",
      description: """
        API requires authorization. All requests must have valid authorization header containing token like:

        `Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...`
      """
    ]
  end
end
```

I was expecting for the :odbc module to be available thus allowing me to connect to SQLServer and instead when I run the remote console on server I get

```
Interactive Elixir (1.9.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(search_service@127.0.0.1)1> SearchService.WorkOrderSyncOut.createWO('c765bc7f-6308-42b3-b5da-647830d5cceb')
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :odbc.start/0 is undefined (module :odbc is not available)
    :odbc.start()
    (search_service) lib/search_service/sync/odbc.ex:5: SearchService.ODBC.start_link/2
    (search_service) lib/search_service/sync/db_connect.ex:45: SearchService.DBConnect.getMSSQLConnection/0
    (search_service) lib/search_service/sync/work_order_sync_out.ex:7: SearchService.WorkOrderSyncOut.createWO/1
```

Thank you in advance for any pointer!

Comment: Please share both your `mix.exs` and the full stacktrace.

Comment: Try to add `included_applications: [:odbc]` into `def application do`. If it does not help, put it into `extra_applications` list. Release won’t include everything you have on your machine by default.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thank you very much, indeed `included_applications: [:odbc]` solved it. If you want to make it an answer I'll approve it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the application into the release, one should explicitly do it.

```
def application do
  [
      mod: {SearchService.Application, []},
      included_applications: [:odbc], # ⇐ THIS
      extra_applications: [:logger, ...]
  ]
end
```

The release differs from local runs because in local you nevertheless have the package compiled and the respective `.beam` is visible to `mix` runner.

Production build is *packaged* and the package includes only those explicitly specified applications / libraries.

*Sidenote:* the attempt to call `Mix.env()` or like from the release code fails in the very same way because `mix` application *is also not included in the release by default*.